# Find the area of the quadrangular region $ABNH $

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the triangle $ABC$ is traced the height $BH$ . By the midpoint $M$ of $AC$ is traced to perpendicluar bisector that intercepts $BC$ in $N$. Calculate the area of the quadrangular region $ABNH$ if the triangle area $ABC= 18\ \mathrm{m^2}$ (Answer: $9\ \mathrm{m^2}$)

My progress:

[image]

$\triangle BCH \sim \triangle CNM \implies \dfrac{MN}{BH}=\dfrac{CM}{CH}$

$S_{ABNH}=18 -S_{ACN} = 18 - \dfrac{MN.CH}{2}$

$S_{BDN}=S_{DHM}\: (\text{by property})$

$S_{BDN}.S_{DHM}=S_{BDH}\cdot S_{DNM}\: (\text{by property})$

$\displaystyle \frac{S_{CMN}}{CN.CM}=\frac{18}{BC\cdot AC}=\frac{S_{BCH}}{CB\cdot CH}$

...?

Comment: For now a month, all your questions (maybe 15 of them) were about areas of elementary shapes. It could be maybe healthy for you to diversify your mathematical interests... :) :) :) By the way, happy new year !

Comment: @JeanMarie  Hello...Happy New Year too...The questions will now be Areas as I am in the Areas chapter which are divided by subject: Triangular areas, Quadrilateral areas(I'm here now), Polygonal region areas and Circular region areas..So, you'll have to wait a while to change the theme...Sorry...:):):)

Comment: Btw, 1) I am curious to know which book are you following ? 2) Are you studying on your own, without the possibility to work with fellows (which is often the best way to progress)... ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  But I've already told you which book I'm using; "Problems in Geometry and how to solve them from the publisher Racso...I just like geometry...and through these exercises I can improve my knowledge that I didn't have in elementary school and be able to help others...it's just a hobby as I'm already finishing college and I have other commitments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $BM$ is a median, $[ABM]=9$. Also, $BH \parallel NM \Rightarrow [NBH]=[MBH]$.

$\therefore [ABNH]=[ABH]+[NBH]=[ABH]+[MBH]=[ABM]=9$.

Comment: thansk for help

Answer (score 2):

Drop perp $NQ$ from $N$ to $BH$. Then, $S_{\triangle BNH} = \frac 12  BH \cdot MH ~$ (as $NQ = MH$)

$S_{ABNH} = S_{\triangle ABH} + S_{\triangle BNH} = \frac 12 BH \cdot (AH + HM)$
$= \frac 12 S_{\triangle ABC} = 9$